# Make shareable task to public group in salesforce

Tags: tasks, public-group

Wanted to make shareable task where any group member can close the task for all group members

there is any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has built the Task functionality which can be performed by an individual and cannot be assigned to group or queue.

Just in case if you want to create same Task records for all the group members then create a custom checkbox field to mark in as group task.

Create a trigger for task creation and when a group member completes the task then you can remove the rest of the tasks from other group members.

Comment: How to identify task associated tasks assigned to other users?

Comment: You need to build the logic.